# Evaluar todos los elementos de un arreglo con if statement, antes de llegar al else statement. C++

Tags: c++, bucle-for, condiciones

Quiero iterar sobre un arreglo char y evaluar si un caracter "x" existe en el arreglo. Si el caracter "x" existe, se ejecuta en bloque de codigo, de lo contrario, se ejecuta otro bloque. Mi problema es que, naturalmente, la evaluación comienza con el elemento[o] del arreglo. Por lo que inmediatamente el programa ejecuta el "else". Quiero encontrar una forma para que se evaluen todos los elementos del arreglo, si nunguno corresponde a "x" entonces ejecutar el "else".

Este es mi codigo :

```
bool checkIfLetterExistOnWord(string word, char letter, char* lettersArray, char* lowDashesArray, bool hasWon, bool hasLost, int lives){

   for(int i = 0; i<word.length(); i++ ){

      if(letter == lettersArray[i]){

         int position = i;
         lowDashesArray[position] = letter;
         cout << letter;
         cout << endl;
         cout << lettersArray[i];
         cout << endl;
         cout << lowDashesArray;
         cout << endl;


         for(int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++){

             if(lettersArray[j] == lowDashesArray[j]){

               cout << "You have won";
                hasWon = true;
                return hasWon;

               }
              else{

                cout << "good job. Guess the next letter";
                cout << endl;
                break;

              }
          }
       }
      else {
           cout << "wrong";
           cout << endl;
           cout << lettersArray[i];
           cout << endl;
          if(lives == 0){

            hasLost = true;
            cout << "You lost";
            return hasLost;


          }
          else {
            lives--;
            cout << "You still have this lives :";
            cout << endl;
            cout << lives;
            cout << endl;

          }
       }
   }

}
```

En este momento sucede lo siguiente:

```
//la palabra a buscar es "hola"
//"hola" es un arreglo de carcateres [h,o,l,a]
//la letra a evaluar es "l"
//como "l" y "h" no son iguales, se ejecuta el else statement.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No razonaste correctamente. Tu problema sucede porque:
**Todo lo que pongas en un ciclo se repetirá.**

Si no quieres que algo se repita debes hacerlo fuera del ciclo. En este caso no puedes hacer dos tareas al mismo tiempo.

Pasarías de un código como este (es un ejemplo parecido y más conciso por simplicidad):

```
string word = "Word";
char letter = 'o';

for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
    if(word[i] == letter){
        cout << "You have won";
    }
    else{
        cout << "Bad luck";
    }
}
```

A esto:

```
string word = "Word";
char letter = 'o';

bool letterFound = false;

for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
    if(word[i] == letter){
        letterFound = true;
    }
}

if(letterFound){
    cout << "You have won";
}
else{
    cout << "Bad luck";
}
```